# Using ANT how to build and deploy a non maven project on Hudson

Tags: java, ant, build-automation

I have a hudson server, want to build and deploy my Non Maven project to Webshpere Application server on periodic basis using ANT Script.

Can any body please help. 
Though found some similar questions but none of them were talking about ANT script so posting the question.

Comment: Do you mean "deploy" to a Maven repository?

Comment: No I want to deploy the web application over webshpere application server.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: Answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1020-ant.html
A very helpful tutorial. Followed and was able to deploy the application.

Answer (score 2):

Hudson knows how to run ant to build your script.

Install Hudson, and install the plugins you need and then create a new job.  Take your time and read all the options